# LEFT OUTER JOIN to check for non-existence relation id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query part

```
left outer join 
(
    select `id`,
        `order_payment_id`,
        `product_id`,
        `product_slug_id`,
        `order_package_id`,
        `name`,
        `price`
    from `web`.`order_products` `$Table`
) `$Inner` on (`$Outer`.`id2` = `$Inner`.`order_payment_id`)
```

But problem is that if

```
$Outer`.`id2` is NULL
```

then i need merge like

```
`$Inner` on (`$Outer`.`order_payment_id` = `$Inner`.`order_payment_id`)
```

So how to write right syntax for condition inside ON ?
expected result

```
left outer join 
(
    select `id`,
        `order_payment_id`,
        `product_id`,
        `product_slug_id`,
        `order_package_id`,
        `name`,
        `price`
    from `web`.`order_products` `$Table`
) `$Inner` on ((IF ISNULL(`$Outer`.`id2`) THEN `$Outer`.`order_payment_id` ELSE `$Outer`.`id2`) = `$Inner`.`order_payment_id`)
```

Comment: check out [IFNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html) function for mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the trick

```
) `$Inner` on (IFNULL(`$Outer`.`order_payment_id2`,`$Outer`.`id2`) = `$Inner`.`order_payment_id`)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function which returns the first non-null value:

```sql
) `$Inner` on COALESCE(`$Outer`.`id2`, `$Outer`.`order_payment_id`) = `$Inner`.`order_payment_id`)
```